# wordpress 4.7 how to create or update post using wp-rest-api

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

can you please explain me how to add post using wp-rest-api.

currently i have get post data using wp-rest-api successfully but i dont know how to update or create post using rest-api.

appreciate your help!
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or Angular ?  ACF fields ?  I can answer this question if still needed.